# Do Leader Mods work with quest turn-ins?

Tags: borderlands

So, I use a Support Gunner mod for my Soldier (solo play) because I enjoy the unlimited ammo it gives me. The idea just occured to me however, that I could possibly use a Leader Mod (that gives extra % Exp) just for turnins. I would equip the extra exp mod, turn in the quest, and then re-equip my Support mod. Would this work?

Comment: Interesting question. I also loved the unlimited ammo mod on my first play-trough. But you seem to be in the best position to test this. Why not test it yourself. (Note that the amount of XP you get for a quest might be set on the moment you accept to do the quest, not when you finish it).

Comment: Searched a little bit, found no answer. Did think of another question, does the experience mod also give bonus Weapon proficiency exp.

Comment: @Ids that IS a good question, you should post that as a standalone. I would, but its your idea so ideally its your rep.

Comment: imo its not worth the effort as you'll get oodles of xp at the last mission and/or crawmerax farming, and also, you can find class mods that regen certain ammo types, so you don't *have* to be a soldier.  My hunter has sniper rifle ammo regen while my siren has SMG ammo regen :)

Comment: @yx i have no idea what you just said. What does being a Soldier have anything to do with my question? (nothing)

Comment: @Ender I just wanted to point out that while the soldier class has an ammo regen class skill, other classes can get specific ammo regen from the class mod as well.  Not really related to your question though

Comment: Ender, feel free to post the question. Rep isn't that important. (Also, FTL that is where it at! ;)).

Comment: Re:Ammo, I usually play with different gun setups. (One sniper, one shotgun, and a two others). So only regening ammo from one gun doesn't do it for me.

Comment: @ender About the crawmerax farming remark. In borderlands 1 with the knoxx DLC there is a endgame boss called crawmerax that is the final challenge. Of course, you can then farm this final challenge to... dunno. Become even better at shooting people in the face after you have already won the game :D.

Comment: Re:Ammo, Ammo loss was never a big factor for me in Borderlands 1, as ammo for a particular weapon went down it seemed to generate in increasing quantities in lootable boxes - if I was on 0 for (one) particular gun type and opened an ammo box, usually 5/6 of them would be ammo for that type. Further to this I generally rotated my weapons (I tried to maintain an even gun proficiency level), which allowed time to replenish ammo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - the Leader Mod does not influence experience gained from handing in quests, as [discussed on the GearBox forum](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=89247). The experience gained from this bonus is pretty much limited to experience from killing enemies.